# Is it safe to trust Microsoft Windows certificate that has passed its expiration date

Tags: windows, windows-11, certificate

Just recently I installed Windows. First I installed Windows 10 shipped with PC. The next day, after receiving info on startup that the PC is Windows 11 eligible, I've updated it to Windows 11 (Update initiated by windows on reboot, finished without issues). Now it is Windows 11, version 22H2. All updates are installed.

Whenever I'm trying to make an administrative task, a pop up shows up, asking if I want to allow an app to make changes on my pc. From what I see, some certificates which were used to sign apps shipped with Windows passed their due date. For example when I access "Manage computer certificates control panel" it says:

- Issued to: Microsoft Windows
- Issued by: Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011
- Valid from 9/2/2021 to 9/1/2022 (And it is the middle of
  2023 already)

According to information presented there, publisher is verified and certificate is ok, but due date passed a long time ago.

I thought that this may change after installing updates, but nothing has changed so far. I'm new in Windows. Is this normal, and I can use those apps, or should I somehow update certificates?

EDIT: I've added info about Windows version above. I see also that the date of modification of the signed app file (in this case C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe) displayed by the system fits in the certificate range (‎Saturday, ‎May ‎7, ‎2022, ‏‎7:20:10 AM)

Answer (score 4):

Windows uses timestamped signatures for Authenticode. If you open the Properties dialog of a signed .exe or .msi file, you'll see that the original author's signature is almost always counter-signed by a time-stamping service. This is done so that signature validity wouldn't depend on whether a certificate is valid *now*, but instead on whether it was valid *at the time of signing.*

So as a result, Windows will keep around quite a few old CAs that have been used for code-signing in the past, if they have merely expired but haven't actually been distrusted for some reason – they're still used for validating old signatures.

If the CA had been actually revoked or distrusted for some reason, that would've been deployed via Windows Update and the cert would no longer show up under "trusted".

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: NO

But: After finding the reason *why the certificate is outdated* this answer *might* become not so strict.

Reason: Especially Microsoft with its continuously almost forced updates will try everything that such a situation will not appear. Valid certificates are an essential part for Microsoft (and others) to prove reliability and keep control over the distributed software. For Microsoft the believing in their reliability is money. Other products (i.e. banking apps) rely on it and their MS-apps would loose their trustworthiness with Microsoft.

##### Outdated Windows Version

> Just recently I installed Windows.

As you're using the tag <kbd>windows-11</kbd> I suppose, you've installed Windows 11.
But which release? *=> Please update your question.*

On a fresh installed windows an outdated Microsoft certificate might result from an old Windows installation media. You probably installed an outdated release of windows 11.
Current release: *Windows 11 Update 2022, Version **22H2***

=> Go to *Settings > Windows Update* and let the system update itself.
These updates are

1. The regular updates
2. The release update
3. Further regular updates

It would have been better to [get the current version of Windows 11 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) for installation.
It might be faster to reinstall with the current version.
BTW: I personally prefer a fresh install to get rid of old garbish as outdated software, their settings, the remains of uninstalled software and personal customization and tweaks that might not fit with the new Windows version.

=> *After this process the error should have vanished.*

If your system does not update please note the annotation of Microsoft:

> [...] If you proceed with installing Windows 11 on a PC that does not meet the requirements, that PC will no longer be supported and won't be entitled to receive updates.

If your hardware does not pass the compatibility test you only have the possibility to update by fresh updated installation media.

=> *This might be an explanation of your issue.

If the certificate check below does not reveal new issues, the certificate issue might be regarded as ok, as the reason is known and plausible (but the problem should be solved by updates)*

##### Malware possible

If your system is up to date and shows this error you should take into account that a software tries to trick you.

1. Verify the app (process name) that you've started:

   - Correct filename? (Is it the expected program? – See the property details)
   - Stored in the expected path?
   - Date plausible? (compare date with other windows components)
2. Is it the same program, every time that problem happens at different admin tasks? *=> Update your question about the details*
3. Verify the certificate that is presented. — Is only the date outdated or the are there also other security constrains?
4. Verify the certification path. — Does it result in the real root certificate of Microsoft or are there deviations?
   Note that everyone can name a selfmade certificate as he likes it. But the fingerprint can almost not be faked.

The certification path:
[image]

Important is the valid path chain to the root certificate that must be the expected one:

```
Subject Name
C (Country):        US
ST (State):         Washington
L (Locality):       Redmond
O (Organization):   Microsoft Corporation
CN (Common Name):   Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010

Issuer Name
C (Country):        US
ST (State):         Washington
L (Locality):       Redmond
O (Organization):   Microsoft Corporation
CN (Common Name):   Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010

Issued Certificate
Version:            3
Serial Number:      28 CC 3A 25 BF BA 44 AC 44 9A 9B 58 6B 43 39 AA
Not Valid Before:   2010-06-23
Not Valid After:    2035-06-23

Certificate Fingerprints
SHA1:   3B 1E FD 3A 66 EA 28 B1 66 97 39 47 03 A7 2C A3 40 A0 5B D5
MD5:    A2 66 BB 7D CC 38 A5 62 63 13 61 BB F6 1D D1 1B

Public Key Info
Key Algorithm:      RSA
Key Parameters:     05 00
Key Size:           4096
Key SHA1 Fingerprint:   88 A9 5A EF C0 84 FC 13 74 41 6B B1 63 32 C2 CF 92 59 BB 3B

Key Usage
Usages: Digital signature Revocation list signature
Critical:   No

Basic Constraints
Certificate Authority:  Yes
Max Path Length:    Unlimited
Critical:   Yes

Subject Key Identifier
Key Identifier: D5 F6 56 CB 8F E8 A2 5C 62 68 D1 3D 94 90 5B D7 CE 9A 18 C4
Critical:   No
```

=> *Compare fingerprints and IDs with yours. If it's not the same, regard your system as compromised.*

---

For easier comparing, here the certificate as *base64 encoded X.509* export:
File: `Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2010.cer`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

---

##### Update:

Sorry, I've been irritated by your question about the outdated certificate. — Now that you've updated your question by `mmc.exe` and the details about it. I've got a new view:

You state:

> Whenever I'm trying to make an administrative task, a pop up shows up, asking if I want to allow an app to make changes on my pc.

Obviously you are not talking about a certificate error, recognized by the system, but you are describing the UAC-request to allow a program to access the system with administrative access rights. — And you are irritated about the outdated signing certificate.

So the answer of user *user1686* hits the point (worth my upvote):
The date interval you see is the live-time of the certificate for the time-stamping signature.

And as *user1686* describes: As the state at the time of signing the code is of interest, all these certificates might be outdated (or even revoked, if this happens after the signing date) but only the root certificate (the one we check above) has to be explicitly trusted by your certification store. If you want to know more about these timestamps, here a quite comprehensive link: [Digital signatures and timestamps](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/digital-signatures.aspx)

Boiled down your question reduces to:

Is the program `C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe` really "authentic"? — In detail:

1. Is the code identical to the state the timestamp signature has signed? AND
2. Is the timestamped signature vaild?

To check, just open the *PowerShell* and issue the following command:

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe" | ft Status
```

or for the full timestamped signature information:

```
Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe" | fl *
```

I suppose you will see:

```
PS C:\> Get-AuthenticodeSignature "C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe" | ft Status

Status
------
Valid
```

In this case, everything is OK and your Management Console just requests the necessary rights for its job.

If it's not "valid", please update your question.

Comment: Hello @dodrg,
Thanks for your reply! How can I export such certificate, so I can see it in the form you posted it?

Comment: When the error shows up, there should be a possibility to see the details of the process. Open it » change to the tab *"Certification Path"* » Select (click on) the root certificate » *"View certificate"* (the selected one will be shown!) — Change to the tab *"Details"* » choose *"Copy to file"* » Choose *"Base-64-encoded X.509"* when exporting.  — The resulting file you can open by `notepad.exe` ## Easier to compare is to save my export to file and compare by their md5 or sha  checksums *(pay attention that both files have the same on the spaces/new-lines before and after the text)*.